# Create an array from multiple JSON files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

Hello I have an array of cities

```
var cityArr = ["London", "Beijing", "Paris", "New York", "Seoul", "HongKong"];
```

I want to iterate through each city and get a JSON API using AngularJS and Javascript, here is my code:

```
for (i=0; i<cityArr.length; i++){

    $scope.$watch('fondCity', function () {
        cityService.city = $scope.foundCity;
    });
    var newUrl = "http://api.waqi.info/feed/" + cityArr[i] + "/?token=5336bd836b9ec064f6c6fe0bf7e2781838c15c87";
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: newUrl
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.newData = response.data;




        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.newData = response.statusText;
        });
    }
```

How can I add each JSON file to one single array.

JSON single file

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "aqi": 49,
    "idx": 5724,
    "attributions": [
      {
        "url": "http://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/",
        "name": "UK-AIR, air quality information resource - Defra, UK"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://londonair.org.uk/",
        "name": "London Air Quality Network - Environmental Research Group, King's College London"
      }
    ],
    "city": {
      "geo": [
        51.5073509,
        -0.1277583
      ],
      "name": "London",
      "url": "http://aqicn.org/city/london/"
    }
}
```

I want it to look like this one:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "aqi": 49,
    "idx": 5724,
    "attributions": [
      {
        "url": "http://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/",
        "name": "UK-AIR, air quality information resource - Defra, UK"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://londonair.org.uk/",
        "name": "London Air Quality Network - Environmental Research Group, King's College London"
      }
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "aqi": 155,
    "idx": 1451,
    "attributions": [
      {
        "url": "http://www.bjmemc.com.cn/",
        "name": "Beijing Environmental Protection Monitoring Center (北京市环境保护监测中心)"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://beijing.usembassy-china.org.cn/070109air.html",
        "name": "U.S Embassy Beijing Air Quality Monitor (美国驻北京大使馆空气质量监测)"
      }
    ],
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "aqi": 28,
    "idx": 5722,
    "attributions": [
      {
        "url": "http://www.airparif.asso.fr/",
        "name": "AirParif - Association de surveillance de la qualité de l'air en Île-de-France"
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each response share the same attributes, the best you can achieve is to have an array of each response.

By using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) you can use the promises of the `$http` and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them together.

```
var promises = cityArr.map(function(name) {
    return $http.get("http://api.waqi.info/feed/" + name + "/?token=5336bd836b9ec064f6c6fe0bf7e2781838c15c87");
});  // For each City Name, create an array filled with Promises.

// Wait for all the Promises to be completed.
$q.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    // Create an array of the data attribute from each response.
    var results = data.map(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    });

    console.log(results);
});
```

You will need to add `$q` as a dependency to your controller or component.

I have created a JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/gukusot/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

Duplicated key definitions in JSONs

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "status": "not ok"
}
```

should not be used.

You should wrap up each JSON reply into an object, and you can concatenate those objects into a single array.

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    var cityArr = ["London", "Beijing", "Paris", "New York", "Seoul", "HongKong"];
    $scope.newData = {};

    angular.forEach(cityArr, function(value) {
    var newUrl = "http://api.waqi.info/feed/" + value + "/?token=5336bd836b9ec064f6c6fe0bf7e2781838c15c87";
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: newUrl
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.newData[value] = response.data;
            console.log($scope.newData);
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.newData[value] = response.statusText;
        });
    });
}
```

Desired result:

```
    [
    "London": {"status": "ok", ...},
    "Beijing": {"status": ... , ... },
    ...
    ]
```

Notes:

1. Do not pollute the global scope, use **var** keyword for loop variables.
2. I would prefer a built-in function to iterate over your array, e.g. angular.forEach.

Comment: This actually is not an an answer to the question but a comment instead. In these kind of situations please try commenting.